# Intergraph SmartMarine Symbol creation

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a Symbol for SM3D. And the port creation always fail. I don't know why. My part class have only one port. I've changed everything I can. Please Help !!!

Here is my code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub ConstructOutputs()
    MyBase.ConstructOutputs()
    Try
        Dim Objeto As Part = InputVar.Value
        Dim SymbolCreator As New SymbolGeometryHelper

        EcoOut.Outputs("Princ") = SymbolCreator.CreateSphere(OccurrenceConnection, 0.001)

        EcoOut.Outputs("Port1") = New PipeNozzle(InputVar.Value, MyBase.OccurrenceConnection, True, 0, New Position(0, 0, 0), New Vector(1, 0, 0), 0.0, True)

        ...
```

Thanks,
Eddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for your case is very simple... Ports in Smart Marine always starts from 1. So you all you have to do is change this argument in the creation of PipeNozzle:

```
Protected Overrides Sub ConstructOutputs()
    MyBase.ConstructOutputs()
    Try
        Dim Objeto As Part = InputVar.Value
        Dim SymbolCreator As New SymbolGeometryHelper

        EcoOut.Outputs("Princ") = SymbolCreator.CreateSphere(OccurrenceConnection, 0.001)

        EcoOut.Outputs("Port1") = New PipeNozzle(InputVar.Value, MyBase.OccurrenceConnection, True, 1, New Position(0, 0, 0), New Vector(1, 0, 0), 0.0, True)
```

Change it and this is going to work!

Comment: Wow man, you're fast. I was stuck with this for an entire week. Thanks

Comment: This is a very common issue.. hehe